# Color Crossword

Tags: word

Okay, I made this puzzle months ago. I remember the rules, but not the answer.

Each row is a word and each box holds one letter. Boxes of the same color are the same letter as well; as there are only 7 colors, the whole puzzle uses only 7 letters. The goal is just figuring out what all 9 words are.

[image: Puzzle Image]

For those with difficulty with colors, below is a text copy of the puzzle; each number matches one of the colors:
123
4352
34265
627534
6215365
52364211
231526726
5211244352
25267347211

Comment: For future reference, you might want to add a [no-computers] tag on questions like this! [Quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/) solves this very easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> blue = S, purple = E, grey = A, yellow = L, green = R, red = T, orange = N
>  SEA
>  LATE
>  ALERT
>  RENTAL
>  RESTART
>  TEARLESS
>  EASTERNER
>  TESSELLATE
>  ETERNALNESS
>  
>  Solved by recognising purple-blue-blue was likely -ESS, then the first word was SEA, then after some trials TESSELLATE popped out and everything else looked obvious. Knowing English letter frequencies helped.

Comment: Beat me to posting while I was writing up the explanation. +1.

Comment: Dammit well done

Comment: That looks right to me. All three answers got it right, so I ticked your answer as it came the earliest.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> SEA / LATE / ALERT / RENTAL / RESTART / TEARLNESS / EASTERNER / TESSELLATE / ETERNALNESS

How I solved it:

> I started with the last word: `-ESS` is a nice suffix for making long words, so I guessed it was probably `-LESS` or `-NESS`.
>  Given the gray letter's position in later words, it was likely a vowel of some sort, so I had to choose A for that one to make the first word SEA. After that, I had the word `E?E??A??ESS`, and the blanks could be filled in pretty easily.

Comment: God dammit...darn it

Answer (score 1):

> Purple is e, red is t, green is r, orange is n, grey is a, yellow is l, blue is s